# How does the Scipy CubicSpline extrapolation work when constraining the second derivative?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

Running the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate

x = np.arange(-3, 4)
y = xs**2
spline = sp.interpolate.CubicSpline(x, y, bc_type=((2, 0), (2, 0)))

x2 = np.arange(-10, 11)
plt.plot(x2, spline(x2), label="y2")
plt.plot(x2, spline(x2, 1), label="y2'")
plt.plot(x2, spline(x2, 2), label="y2''")
plt.plot(x2, spline(x2, 3), label="y2'''")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

produces an estimate where the extrapolated tails bend down:

[image: plot of a spline]

Why do the tails bend down in the extrapolated regions? My intuition was that the estimated values would have reasonably approximated the parabola on the interior region of the spline, with the tail values being the result of a linear extrapolation.

Also, I understand that by imposing "natural" spline boundary conditions I have absolutely produced a worse fit for this particular function, but I'm trying to understand how the `bc_type` parameter works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says:

> extrapolate to out-of-bounds points based on first and last intervals

For example, all it does for x < -3 is to use the same formula as it used for -3 < x < -2, the leftmost interval between knots. Similarly, the formula for x > 4 is the same that was used for 3 < x < 4.

These will be some cubic polynomials that interpolate two values that they were supposed to interpolate, but cannot be expected to follow any large scale pattern in the function.

Simply put, this extrapolation is useless. Splines are not, and were never meant to be, useful as extrapolation tools.

[InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline) has a slightly more sensible option for extrapolation, which is by nearest boundary value (extending the graph by horizontal lines). But if you want something that actually follows the large scale behavior of the data, don't look in `scipy.interpolate` module: check out `curve_fit` from `optimization` instead.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes total sense, I must have overlooked that piece in the docs. I agree though that that is borderline useless extrapolation behavior.